# aws-iam-authenticator daemon set not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-iam-authenticator

I'm trying to setup the `aws-iam-authenticator` container on AWS EKS, but I've been stuck for hours trying to get the daemon started. I'm following the instructions found on the [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) repo, and I'm using the [deploy/example.yml](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/blob/master/deploy/example.yaml) as my reference starting point. I've already modified the roles, clusterID, and another required components but still no luck after applying the deployment.

I just enabled logging for the controller-master so I hope there may be some further details in there. I also came across a post where folks mentioned restarting the controller nodes, but I haven't found a way to do it using EKS yet.

If anyone has quick tips or other places to check, I'd greatly appreciate it :)

```
$ kubectl get ds -n kube-system
    NAME                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
    aws-iam-authenticator   0         0         0       0            0           node-role.kubernetes.io/master=   8h
    aws-node                3         3         3       3            3           <none>                            3d22h
    kube-proxy              3         3         3       3            3           <none>                            3d22h
```

Additional outputs

```
$ kubectl get ds aws-iam-authenticator -n kube-system --output=yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"DaemonSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"aws-iam-authenticator"},"name":"aws-iam-authenticator","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"selector":{"matchLabels":{"k8s-app":"aws-iam-authenticator"}},"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod":""},"labels":{"k8s-app":"aws-iam-authenticator"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"args":["server","--config=/etc/aws-iam-authenticator/config.yaml","--state-dir=/var/aws-iam-authenticator","--generate-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/kubeconfig.yaml"],"image":"602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-iam-authenticator:v0.4.0","name":"aws-iam-authenticator","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m","memory":"20Mi"},"requests":{"cpu":"10m","memory":"20Mi"}},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/etc/aws-iam-authenticator/","name":"config"},{"mountPath":"/var/aws-iam-authenticator/","name":"state"},{"mountPath":"/etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/","name":"output"}]}],"hostNetwork":true,"nodeSelector":{"node-role.kubernetes.io/master":""},"serviceAccountName":"aws-iam-authenticator","tolerations":[{"effect":"NoSchedule","key":"node-role.kubernetes.io/master"},{"key":"CriticalAddonsOnly","operator":"Exists"}],"volumes":[{"configMap":{"name":"aws-iam-authenticator"},"name":"config"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/"},"name":"output"},{"hostPath":{"path":"/var/aws-iam-authenticator/"},"name":"state"}]}},"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-24T06:47:54Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    k8s-app: aws-iam-authenticator
  name: aws-iam-authenticator
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "601895"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/daemonsets/aws-iam-authenticator
  uid: 63e8985a-54cc-49a8-b343-3e20b4d9eaff
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: aws-iam-authenticator
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: aws-iam-authenticator
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - server
        - --config=/etc/aws-iam-authenticator/config.yaml
        - --state-dir=/var/aws-iam-authenticator
        - --generate-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/kubeconfig.yaml
        image: 602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-iam-authenticator:v0.4.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: aws-iam-authenticator
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/aws-iam-authenticator/
          name: config
        - mountPath: /var/aws-iam-authenticator/
          name: state
        - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/
          name: output
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: aws-iam-authenticator
      serviceAccountName: aws-iam-authenticator
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
        operator: Exists
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: aws-iam-authenticator
        name: config
      - hostPath:
          path: /etc/kubernetes/aws-iam-authenticator/
          type: ""
        name: output
      - hostPath:
          path: /var/aws-iam-authenticator/
          type: ""
        name: state
  templateGeneration: 4
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 0
  desiredNumberScheduled: 0
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  numberReady: 0
  observedGeneration: 4
```

Comment: can you describe the daemonset and add the output...also kubectl get events

Comment: I have a hunch that it might be due to the `nodeSelector` specification. Try removing it and see if they get scheduled.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I was looking at that earlier, and sure enough commenting it out brought up the pods! I'll accept this as the answer if you can move it to a response :). Any idea why it would cause the issue if the entry was like a wildcard for any node? Sidenote, I'm getting CrashLoopBack errors, but I'll troubleshoot that separately since that should be "easier" to hunt down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `nodeSelector` field. According to [k8s docs for label selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors), empty string does not always denote a wildcard and behavior depends on the implementation of that specific API:

> The semantics of empty or non-specified selectors are dependent on the context, and API types that use selectors should document the validity and meaning of them.

I'm not seeing the empty behavior for DaemonSet's `nodeSelector` in its official docs, but this [GCE example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset#creating_daemonsets) specifically says to `omit the nodeSelector field to schedule on all nodes`, which you confirmed worked in your case as well.